# What is causing this mvc razor syntax error?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

```
var openWos = @Model.MyMaintenanceDashboard.OpenWorkOrders;
```

Why is Visual Studio saying this is a syntax error? It runs fine, but what would the proper syntax be?

Update: OpenWos is a javascript variable

Comment: Is the `var openWos` bit JavaScript or C# code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a javascript code, then you need to quote it so that you do not get the 'syntax' error.

```
var openWos = '@Model.MyMaintenanceDashboard.OpenWorkOrders';
```

Comment: There is a difference between this and the original code posted. This results in the JS var being a string type rather than a number. There should not be a syntax error in either use, with or without quotes.

Comment: @RJCuthbertson, There is a syntax error in VS without the quotes (and its easy enough to test yourself). It compiles and runs fine either either way, its just an annoying issue with the razor templating engine.

Comment: Maybe it's only a syntax error in certain versions of VS? It doesn't report a syntax error in VS 2013 and MVC 4 or MVC 5. I did test it, did not receive a syntax error, and consequently informed the OP that there shouldn't be a syntax error with or without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're setting a C# `var`, the correct syntax would be without the `@` in front of `Model` as you're already in a C# code block:

```
@{
    var openWos = Model.MyMaintenanceDashboard.OpenWorkOrders;
}
```

**Edit:**

You've clarified that this is a JavaScript variable. There shouldn't be a syntax error at all, as this is valid Razor. There is a distinct difference between quoting the value as suggested by Stephen, and the code that you posted originally. The type of the JavaScript variable is a string when quoted instead of a number.

For example, including this in a page:

```
<script>
    @{ int z = 10; }

    var x = @z;
    console.log(x);
    console.log(typeof x);

    var y = '@z';
    console.log(y);
    console.log(typeof y);
</script>
```

Results in the following being logged to the console:

```
10
number
10
string
```

And there is no syntax error reported using the variable `@z` in either instance.

Comment: openWos is a javascript variable, not C#

Comment: If that's the case, there should not be a syntax error at all. It's valid Razor. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that you can get around this by adding zero:

```
var openWos = @Model.MyMaintenanceDashboard.OpenWorkOrders + 0;
```